# execute shell script in remote machine is not working from azure pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines, powershell-remoting

I have a scenario like, calling PowerShell script file from azure devops pipeline,
It is running background and updated the text file, inside I have a code for launch .cmd or batch  and power shell file, but it is not working.

please check the image for pipeline configuration to execute shell script in remote machine

[image]

Script file

```
cd C:\Data\TestExecutioner
Set-Content -Path C:\Data\TestExecutioner\Test.txt -Value 'Hello, World'
cmd /c C:\Data\TestExecutioner\Execute_TE_Smoke.cmd
```

and Execute_TE_Smoke file contains to start Test Execute tool.

while deploy a pipe, powershell window or .cmd is not running but the text file is updated

Comment: Hi Babu TC, and welcome to Stack Overflow!. Can I make a request; could you paste the relevant bit of YAML from your pipeline into the question? It'd make it easier to understand what is happening. Remember, on this site you're encouraged to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72041042/edit) your questions to add clarity and detail as needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.